# How to launch/GetState/Terminate a process in mac

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to launch a process, intermittently check its state whether it is running/not-responding/exited, and in the end, terminate it. In windows I did the following and it works:
=> CreateProcess to launch
=> GetExitCodeProcess for checking its state intermittently (though couldn't find a way for checking a not-responding state)
=> TerminateProcess to terminate.

For mac I am trying following using NSRunningApplication:
=> launchApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error to launch
=> terminated property of NSRunningApplication class for getting the current status intermittently.
=> terminate method of NSRunningApplication class for terminate

The application is launched successfully. Problem is with caching NSRunningApplication* returned by the lauch call. The pointer is good to use in the function where the process is launched. But afterwards when its state is checked or it is called to terminate the process, it is throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with the approach. Or any other alternative way to achieve the requirement.

Comment: Since you haven't supplied any code, it's hard to guess why you're getting a bad access error.  Perhaps you're not retaining the NSRunningApplication instance that you've obtained?  But in any case it sounds like NSTask is probably closer to what you want anyway; I would recommend that you switch to using that and see how it goes.

Comment: This is a memory management problem. Unlike Windows, OSX has built-in memory management with reference counting. Have a look at this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html